# react native jwt auth basic api

Tags: api, react-native, jwt

The information they give me is that the API is already on a server
and I can only make requests type GET and requires different parameters for the endpoint of login need the parameter "data"
that carries these values {"user": "juan", "userid": "123", "passw": "000"}

what I need is to know how I can consume the API that I can only make GET requests and requires parameters from React Native
login() {

```
fetch (Api/a/login',{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization', 'Basic ' + "here should go a token or parameters"
    //'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(this.state.user+ ":" + this.state.userid+ ":" + this.state.password)
    }
body: JSON.stringify({   // I don't know if I need you to wear this "body"
        user: this.state.user,
    userid: this.state.userid,
        password: this.state.password
  }),
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) =>{
      console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
   }).done();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
const username = "julian";
const userid = 123;
const passw = "000";

fetch (`Api/a/login?user=${username}&userid=${userid}&password=${passw}`,{
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        Accept: 'application/json',
        Authorization', 'Basic ' + "here should go a token or parameters"
    //'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(this.state.user+ ":" + this.state.userid+ ":" + this.state.password)
    }
}).then((response) => response.json())
  .then((responseData) =>{
      console.log("LoginData:-" + JSON.stringify(responseData));
   }).done();
}
```

When passing the parameters in the URL you can remove the body.

Comment: thanks, in the authentication i would have to put                                                  Authorization', 'Basic ' + "here should go a token or parameters"
//'Authorization', 'Basic ' + base64.encode(this.state.user+ ":" + this.state.userid+ ":" + this.state.password)